# How much resources does preprocessing generally use?

Tags: performance, resources, artificial-intelligence, preprocessor, convolution

I'm learning about CNN's (Convolutional Neural Networks) and the wiki page says, "Convolutional networks were inspired by ... and are variations of multilayer perceptrons which are designed to use minimal amounts of preprocessing."

So could one say that a characteristic of the variations of multilayer perceptrons leads to minimal amounts of preprocessing?

If so, how much resources does preprocessing usually take up?

Does using this technique of data mining introduce a new model for minimizing preprocessing?

Comment: Do you have some code you'd like for us to examine?

Comment: umm nope... just a general cs question

Comment: You will have better luck asking this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/, which is specifically for machine learning. I would say a big benefit of CNN's is that you don't need to invent your own features manually--the network will try to find the best set of features for understanding the given problem.